# href returns as undefined only when anchor element has children

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a delay when you click on a link so that I can use a fade in/out transition on my webpage.
I am using .href to get the href of all the anchor tags, which works perfect when the anchor tag has no children. However, if it does have a child element, it only returns as undefined. Is there any way to work around this?

```js
const tran = document.querySelectorAll('.tran'); //you can ignore this
const anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');

setTimeout(() => { //only for the page transition
  tran.forEach(elem => {
    elem.classList.remove('pageTran');
  });
}, 330);

for (let i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
  const anchor = anchors[i];

  anchor.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let target = e.target.href;

    tran.forEach(elem => {
      elem.classList.add('pageTran');
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      window.location.href = target;
      //this is where I have issues, targets value is Undefined if <a> has a child
    }, 330);

  });
};
```

```html
<a href="/index.html"></a> <!--this works perfect-->

<a href="/index.html"><img src="/images/example.png"></a> <!--this returns undefined-->
```

I have tried using e.target.*getAttribute('href')*; instead of e.target.href;, but that has the same problem except it returns as null instead of undefined. I'm really stumped on this, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Change `e.target.href` to `e.currentTarget.href`

Comment: use event delegation, where instead of adding an event listener to each link individually, you add it to the entire document and use the event's "target" property to check if the clicked element has an href attribute. This would allow it to work even if the link is wrapped in another element. Additionally, instead of using the setTimeout function, you could use the "transitionend" event to wait for the page transition to complete before redirecting to the new page. This would ensure that the page change only happens once the transition has finished.

Comment: theres a problem with above code as it will only work if the link element itself has an href attribute. If the link is wrapped in another element, such as a <span> or <div>, the event listener will not work because the target is not the <a> element itself.

Comment: to be honest, just use `let target = anchor` ... or just refactor the code to use `anchor` instead of `target` ...